# Is it possible to run vim in remote mode on another machine?

Tags: vim

I run an Ubuntu server virtualbox under a Windows host for web development.

At the moment I do all editing in Vim running inside PuTTY. It runs pretty well, but lacks some useful features like native copypasting from the host.

I know about the remote mode of Vim, but afaik it can only operate on the same machine.

Question is, is it possible to make gVim on the windows host proxy all the commands (and the editing) to a Vim instance running on the Linux guest?

UPDATE: final solution:

1. `apt-get install vim-gtk` on the client
2. install XMing on the host
3. create a shortcut with XLaunch, providing `gvim` as the program name and your PuTTY saved session name as the computer name.
4. done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting up a XServer (like XMing or cygwin/X) on your windows machine and use X forwarding?

This way you can run an instance of gVim on your linux host and have it displayed on your Windows machine.

See http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/misc/xwindows.html for a short guide how to make this work in windows.